# Insert data into table with result from another select query

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I am seeking help on the following issue:
I have two tables
`Table_1` columns are `itemid`, `locationid`, `quantity`

`Table_2` columns are `itemid`, `location1`, `location2`, `location3`

I want to copy data from `Table_1` (only `quantity` column) into `Table_2` (into `location1` column). The `itemid` are same in both the tables(`Table_1` has duplicate item id's) so that's the reason I want to copy to a new table and keep all quantity in one single row with each location as a column. I am using the below query but it doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO 
Table_2(location1) 
(
 SELECT qty 
 FROM Table_1 
 WHERE locationid = 1 AND Table_1.locationid = Table_2.locationid
)
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If `table_2` is empty, then try the following insert statement:

```
insert into table_2 (itemid,location1) 
select itemid,quantity from table_1 where locationid=1
```

If `table_2` already contains the `itemid` values, then try this update statement:

```
update table_2 set location1=
(select quantity from table_1 where locationid=1 and table_1.itemid = table_2.itemid)
```

Comment: Just this is enough if you have same columns: `insert into table_2 select itemid,quantity from table_1 where locationid=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`product` ( `p1`, `p2`, `p3`) 
SELECT sum(p1), sum(p2), sum(p3) 
FROM `test`.`product`;
```

Answer (score -3):

Below is an example of such a query:

```
INSERT INTO [93275].[93276].[93277].[93278] ( [Mobile Number], [Mobile Series], [Full Name], [Full Address], [Active Date], company ) IN 'I:\For Test\90-Mobile Series.accdb
SELECT [1].[Mobile Number], [1].[Mobile Series], [1].[Full Name], [1].[Full Address], [1].[Active Date], [1].[Company Name]
FROM 1
WHERE ((([1].[Mobile Series])="93275" Or ([1].[Mobile Series])="93276")) OR ((([1].[Mobile Series])="93277"));OR ((([1].[Mobile Series])="93278"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Two things on this anwer. 1) code should be formatted. Indent it by four spaces.  2) It's best to explain *why* your code solves the questioner's problem.