# Managing Locks MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron, locks

I have created a two CRON Jobs which basically runs every 6 and 8 mins respectively . 
The CRON Job basically inserts a set of records and then update some columns in the table

Now the issue that I am facing is that the table is having too many locks which affects the select queries on the table and that prevents users from seeing anything when they visit the site

The query that I have written to insert and update is like this

```
foreach($records as $items)
{
  $query="insert into tablename (column1,column2) values ('$item[0]','$item[1]);
  mysql_query($query);

}
```

same holds true for update

The database is MySQL with MyISAM engine

I would like to know how can I resolve this locking issue

Comment: Use innodb engine, which is row level locking system... MYISAM is table level locking..

Comment: @user1844933 is right to locking, this looks lengthy way to insert data in database, you should use batch insert or if the $records from also database fetched then INSERT - SELECT would be useful and fast. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354132/insert-data-into-table-with-result-from-another-select-query)

Comment: may also use INSERT DELAYED (MYISAM Engine only) also use export