# query result array in loop for another query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I Queried Database Table 'users' for 'user_id'. and get an array of ids.

```
$sel = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE status='Approved'";     
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $sel);
```

Then i inserted values into another table income for all those user ids.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
$ins = "INSERT INTO income (user_id, income_amount)  VALUES ('$row', '100')";       
$giv = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $ins);
}
```

Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\project\t.php on line 109

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: `$row` is array. And `user_id` should be string. `Var_dump($row)` and choose a proper value of `user_id` from it.

Comment: On Var_dump($row) it says array(1) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" } ,array(1) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" } ......

Comment: Just because data is in your database does not mean it is secure. You should still use prepared statements. Also don't suppress errors when debugging.

Comment: @Pyarey so it should be "VALUES ('" . $row['user_id'] . "', '100')";

Comment: @chris85 I must be missing the context of that!

Comment: 2nd level sql injection attack

Comment: If you insert data with a prepared statement the malicious data is stored in the DB. If you then access that data and re-insert it directly to a query you just injected yourself.

Comment: You can do it all in one query... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354132/insert-data-into-table-with-result-from-another-select-query?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks @JungleZombie. It helped me do what i was trying to do. Help from all you guys is valuable.

Comment: But can you help me with Security issue you are talking about @chris85.

Comment: Take a look at this doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and this thread as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php. Avoid inserting data directly to a query unless it is static (e.g. your `100` above).

Answer (score 1):

```
$sel = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE status='Approved'";     
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $sel); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
$ins = "INSERT INTO income (user_id, income_amount)  VALUES ('" . $row['user_id'] . "', '100')";       
$giv = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $ins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First , Check if  $results is in array ..you can put some error handling checked is_array($result).

If it is fine then pass it to mysqli_fetch_array().
Do't add suppress @ error ,while developing.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to suggest you a single query for that so after that you need not to use while loop to insert your data in income table:

Just try it :

```
INSERT INTO income (user_id,income_amount) SELECT user_id,'100' AS income_amount FROM users WHERE status = 'Approved';
```

You can use it like that way :

```
$sel = "INSERT INTO income (user_id,income_amount) SELECT user_id,'100' AS income_amount FROM users WHERE status = 'Approved'";     
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $sel);
```

Comment: I have created a demo scenario on local database. After that i am suggesting it to you. Wish this will help you.