# MySql: Copy data from one table to another with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'd like to copy data from one table to another.

I'd like to copy some data, let's say: "Andy". His number is "5" and his data is "cool".
This is stored in table 1.

Now i'd like to insert the data "cool" into table 2 WHERE number is "5".

**SQL**

```
INSERT TO table2 SET data = (SELECT data FROM table1 WHERE number = table2.number)
```

So, this should copy data from multiply users, like a loop.

How should i do this?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps This don't explain how the data match in diferent tables?

Comment: Misread the SQL statement, [this is what you are looking for I believe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354132/insert-data-into-table-with-result-from-another-select-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the values of Table2 from values of Table1, you can use update statement with joins.

```
UPDATE  Table2
JOIN Table1  ON Table1.number = Table2.number
SET Table2.data = Table1.data;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!